# Revit Api.. How can I set the "View Template" parameter to none? I am using C# to duplicate a view

Tags: c#, revit-api, autodesk

I am duplicating a View using the API through an external Application but I want to set the "View Template" type parameter to none once it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting its [`ViewTemplateId` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/2559f20b-87d4-e879-3139-7f555b251b71.htm) to [`InvalidElementId`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/08ae8886-6ab3-3ef5-d2e0-0da2ffa7bd2c.htm).